# accept method of CompilationUnit

Tags: parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I have used [Standalone ASTParser](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/01/a-complete-standalone-example-of-astparser/) to read the variable names, but it only shows the first declared variable. It is probably because of the addition of **bw.close()** but I can't get where else to put it. Moreover, I can't understand how **accept** method of CompilationUnit can print all declared variables when ASTParser constructor is called only once.

```
final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

    cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {

        Set names = new HashSet();
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment node) {
            SimpleName name = node.getName();
            this.names.add(name.getIdentifier());
            try {
                bw.write("writin");
                bw.write("Declaration of '"+name+"' at line"+cu.getLineNumber(name.getStartPosition()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false; // do not continue to avoid usage info
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your whole code, I can only guess...

From what you said, I believe, you are calling `bw.close()` somewhere during your `visit` method? You should change that, so the `BufferedWriter` is only closed (and flushed), after the visiting is finished. To do this, declare a `final BufferedWriter bw` variable outside of the visitor scope and then `close()` it in a finally block.

Here is a complete example:

```
public static void parse(String fileContent) {

    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);       
    parser.setSource(fileContent.toCharArray());

    final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
    final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    final BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);

    try{
        cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
            public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment node) {
                SimpleName name = node.getName();
                try {
                    bw.write("writing ");
                    bw.write("Declaration of '"+name+"' at line "+cu.getLineNumber(name.getStartPosition()));
                    bw.write("\n");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return false; // do not continue to avoid usage info
            }
        });
    } finally{
        try {
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(writer.getBuffer());
}
```

If you use the following class as (text) input,

```
class TestClass{
    private Object field1;
    private Object field2;
}
```

you should see a similar output to this:

```
writing Declaration of 'field1' at line 4
writing Declaration of 'field2' at line 5
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. I also intend to find out data type of declared variable. Is there a way to do it.

Comment: In this case you should be visiting `FieldDeclaration` instead of `VariableDeclarationFragment` and call `FieldDeclaration#getType()`. You can then also get the `VariableDeclarationFragments` as a `List` by calling `FieldDeclaration#fragments()`.

Comment: Is it the case that FieldDeclaration covers only those variables which are declared outside method? If so, is there any efficient method other than that of visiting the methods.

Comment: `FieldDeclaration` represents the `ASTNode` for one statement of field declaration like e.g. `private Object field1, field2;`. The corresponding node for variables inside a method like `Object var1, var2;` would be `VariableDeclarationStatement. Both can have multible `VariableDeclarationFragments` as their childs like `field1`, `fields2`, `var1` and `var2`.

Comment: `is there any efficient method other than that of visiting the methods` - It depends on what you want to do, and if you already know the structure of the parsed classes. You could also traverse the ASTNode by manually getting the children of each node, but I would normally suggest using a visitor.